# Socket emit only receiving first object in array

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Simply trying to emit an array of data.

Example of an array I am emitting:

```
[
 {
   userid: 1,
   usertag: "random"
 }
 name: "cool",
 age: 10
]
```

The server receives it but only returns the object inside the array.

 So in this example it only returns:

```
[
 {
   userid: 1,
   usertag: "random"
 }
]
```

So I am missing the `name` value and `age` value.

Comment: Your first snippet of code is not valid JavaScript syntax. Did you mean  something like `[ { userid: 1, usertag: "random" }, { name: "cool", age: 10 } ]`?

Comment: It is valid @LucaPolito? Just showed the return of it. This is how it would be made: 
`let someArr = []
let someObj = {
 userid: 1,
 usertag: "random"
}
someArr.push(someObj)
someArr.name = "cool"
someArr.age = 10 `

Comment: You're modifying the `someArr` array object, however note that `socket.io` will encode the object in JSON, so your extra properties `name` and `age` will be lost.

Comment: You can do something like: `let obj = { name: "cool", age: 10, arr: [ { userid: 1, usertag: "random" } ] };`